# How do I keep the same auto-incrementing ids when inserting data into the same table across servers/databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a lookup table that has 3 rows:

```
id | name
=== =======
 1   Pendig
 2   Sent
 3   Failed
```

When I insert this data into the another table on another server/database, how can I ensure the same values (names) are created with the same auto-incrementing ids?

Since it is a lookup table, can I just insert into the table and specify the id?

Comment: Note that copying data from one server to others can be handled by [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html), which offers several advantages over manually copying data. Alternatively, a [federated DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) (using the [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)) can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always overwrite the insert ID in an auto_increment table by specifying it:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Sent');
```

and `2` will be stuff into the table as the ID value. This works perfectly until any OTHER inserts are performed and the table's built-in auto_increment value happens to come up to a value that you yourself inserted, e.g, assuming a brand new freshly created table:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Sent'); // force an ID
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'foo'); // DB assigns 1
INSERT INTO yourtable (name) VALUES ('foo'); // DB assigns 2
```

The first query succeeds, the second query succeeds, the third query fails with a primary key violation, because the DB-generated '2' id now conflicts with the one you inserted manually.

If you want to ensure ID and auto_increment compatibility between different DB instances, then use `mysql_dump` to spit out the table for you. It'll ensure that all the IDs in the table are preserved, and that the internal auto_increment pointer is also sent across properly.

Comment: Marc, thanks, I just tested this and it worked.  I will know the id's ahead of time, so it looks like I can just have insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the lookup table to begin with it should be irrelevant what the `id` actually is.  That is to say that you should never look at the `id` itself and only use it for joins and the like.  If you want to look up this transparent `id`, you should use the `name`.

To answer your specific question, yes you can specify auto increment IDs during inserts:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Pendig')
```